# python opencv imread intermittently returns None on macOS

Tags: python, macos, opencv

Even though the (TIFF) file definitely exists (whether the path is relative or absolute), `cv2.imread` is (sometimes) returning `None` on macOS:

```
image = cv2.imread(filename)
```

opencv is at version 2.4.13.2.

The filenames contain `.` and `_`.

It's the intermittent behaviour that is puzzling me.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: When you say intermittent, do you mean it's happening on some images and not others, or do you mean it sometimes reads and sometimes doesn't read the same image? If the former, can you post an example `.TIF` image that gives you this behavior?

Comment: The same image. I can't post these particular ones, but I will try to find one that I can.

Comment: From [OpenCV docs on `imread()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imread) "On ... MacOSX*, the codecs shipped with an OpenCV image (..., libtiff, ...) are used by default. So, OpenCV can always read ...TIFFs. On MacOSX, there is also an option to use native MacOSX image readers. But beware that currently these native image loaders give images with different pixel values because of the color management embedded into MacOSX." --- so you may have a problem with `libtiff` or the native loaders if you didn't build with `libtiff`.

Comment: I suspect it's something like this, but I'm not completely sure how to proceed on diagnosing and fixing it.

Comment: Update your version of libtif to the latest and see if that fixes your issues.

Answer (score 0):

For me installation of `opencv-python` package from pypi helped.

In my case it was within conda environment with python 3.7.
So generally steps were:

1. activating env: `conda activate my-env`
2. call `pip install opencv-python`: install package in *addition* to main opencv conda packages: `opencv`, `libopencv`, `py-opencv`